# Flutter text widget not centered

Tags: flutter

I am trying to have text centered inside a container. No matter what I did, text is never centered. Here is my code:

```
Container(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  width: 47,
  height: 47,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey, shape: BoxShape.circle),
  child: Text(
    firstName == null && lastName == null
        ? 'UU'
        : '${firstName[0]}${lastName[0]}'.toUpperCase(),
    style: TextStyle(
      fontFamily: 'AvenirLTStd-Roman',
      fontSize: 18,
      color: Colors.white,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
    ),
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  ),
)
```

And this is how the screen is generated:

[image]

If you notice text is not centered, the bottom part of the container seems to have more "free space" compared to the top. When I open this in widget inspector and highlight Text Widget I see this:

[image]

Does anyone know what am I missing here and why is text not centered? I want text to be in the middle of the container and have equal space between top and bottom.

UPDATE:

Using Center widget does not help:

[image]

Comment: Did you tried using "height" inside TextStyle ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your Container with Center.
Center -> Container

Comment: Wrapping Container in Center does not work either

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the text with `Center()`. Or use mediaquery like:

```
 height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 0.5 inside SizedBox()
```

Comment: it does not work using Center widget

Comment: Then you can use mediaquery like ```height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 0.5``` inside SizedBox()

Answer (score 0):

Try to

```
Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      width: 47,
      height: 47,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey, shape: BoxShape.circle),
      child: Center(child: Text(
        firstName == null && lastName == null
            ? 'UU'
            : '${firstName[0]}${lastName[0]}'.toUpperCase(),
          style: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: 'AvenirLTStd-Roman',
          fontSize: 18,
          color: Colors.white,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
        ),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),),
    )
```

[image]

Comment: it does not work using Center widget

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
Container(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  height: 47,
  width: 47,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey, shape: BoxShape.circle),
  child: Text(
  'UU',
  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
),)
```

[image]

Comment: I have no idea, same code does not work for me, it could be some of parent widgets messing it up

Comment: can you share your class or widget tree

Answer (score 0):

Please remove or change fontFamily it will fix it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).